# Retrieve Element from xml file

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to retrieve and display all value from XML file.

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     StorageFile xmlFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Content1.xml");
     XmlDocument xmlDoc;
     xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlFile);                 
     System.Xml.Linq.XDocument duc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.GetXml());

     //var query = from Date in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Serial")
     var query = from Date in duc.Root.Elements("Serial")
                 where Date.Attribute("No").Value == "1"
                 from Current in Date.Elements("Current")
                 select new
                 {
                     value = Current.Attribute("EnglishDate").Value,
                     Arabic = Current.Attribute("ArabicDate").Value,
                     NarratedBy = Current.Attribute("Narrated").Value,
                     Content = Current.Attribute("HadithBody").Value,
                     TransmittedBy = Current.Attribute("RefferedBy").Value,
                     RefferedVerses = Current.Attribute("RefferedVerses").Value
                 };

     foreach (var Date in query)
     {
        xmlTextBlock.Text=String.Format("{0}\t{1}",Date.NarratedBy,Date.Value,Date.Arabic,Date.Content,Date.TransmittedBy,Date.RefferedVerses)+Environment+NewLine;
     }        
}
```

This is my XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Hadith>
    <Serial No="1">
      <Current EnglishDate="22 January 2013"
               ArabicDate="10 Rabi-Ul-Awal 1434"
               Narrated="Narrated Hasan:"
               HadithBody="Knowledge is of two types.Firstly,knowledge perceived by the heart,and that is useful knowledge"
               RefferedBy="Transmitted by:"
               RefferedVerses="Darimi-Al-Timidhi-Hadith 270">
     </Current>
   </Serial>
 </Hadith>
```

This code is not displaying all the values. What do I have to do to display all the values which I declared in the XMLfile?

Comment: Could you paste the XML you're using as well please

Comment: your `string.Format` has two formatstrings specified `{0}`, `{1}`, but 6 arguments. Is it those values that you are not seeing or are you missing values from the XML file?

Comment: to accept 6 arguments what should i do?

Comment: you should add more `{x}`, where `x` is the argument index passed to [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: now i changed the foreach loop like this:
        xmlTextBlock.Text=String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",Date.NarratedBy,Date.Value,Date.Arabic,Date.Content,Date.TransmittedBy,Date.RefferedVerses)+Environment.NewLine;
 when i run my project then its showing  this error:Object Reference not Set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

Modify your **foreach** loop code:

```
xmlTextBlock.Text= String.Empty;
foreach (var Date in query)
     {
        xmlTextBlock.Text += String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\n",
                     Date.NarratedBy,Date.Value,Date.Arabic,Date.Content,
                     Date.TransmittedBy,Date.RefferedVerses);
     }
```

Comment: i modified the foreach loop then also its showing this error: Object Reference not Set to an instance of an object